# What data structure will be best to store the order of explored nodes in an occupancy grid?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have multiple robots, which explore an occupancy grid through some algorithm. I am trying to save the order of explored nodes. But I am not sure, which data structure can be used to save them efficiently.

I first thought of an tree, but the order can be repeatable like 1, 2, 5, 1. So, I feel, it may be too complex to store such an order in tree form. Then, I thought of an array, but it can be too much expensive in terms of memory for large grids.

I am a bit confused now. What data structure would be better(suppose grid is of 10,000 nodes). But the point is the order of explored nodes will be greater than 10,000 in this case as there will be overlap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A tree makes little sense here with a need to preserve insertion order and the need to allow duplicates. Basically, as I understand it, we want to store the path in which the robot has traveled in the tightest form we can.

A compact, contiguous kind of sequence ends up making the most sense here (array, e.g.). It's cheaper than any linked structure (tree included) since there are no links to store.

There's little we can do to compact memory usage any further.

However, an unrolled list might be helpful here. Since it's not one giant contiguous block and instead a series of smaller blocks (ex: 4 kilobytes each) linked together, you can start, say, off-loading blocks at the front of the list to disk if you want to reduce memory use. The link overhead is trivial since we're only storing a link every N elements, where N could be some large number.